# Heating system overhaul: Euroconus fittings - connecting using "normal" fittings

Tags: heating, fitting, copper-pipe

My house has an old-ish copper pipe driven heating system in need of modernization - I'd like to have a new distributor/collector unit that will be capable of being used with electronic control.

I have found that the new heating distributor-collector parts have a connection called "Euroconus". These seem to have a special kind of fitting, with a conical part - however, they have standard gauges and seemingly fitting threads to standard parts...

[image: Euroconus distributor]

There are fittings that connect 20mm copper pipes to 3/4" Euroconus type connectors.

[image: Euroconus fitting for copper pipe]

Problem is, we have 22mm piping - and there is no Euroconus fitting for that, 18mm is the largest for copper pipes.

Would it be possible to just use the "normal" threaded parts like this below?
[image: Standard fitting for copper pipe]

Comment: Is the copper fitting in the last photo meant to be used with a flat rubber washer?  Do you have a manifold or other fitting designed to be used with that copper fitting and can you include a photo of that too?

Comment: Have you considered using an 18x22 mm reducing coupling?  They aren't common but they exist.

Comment: @jay613 Yes, I considered using a 18->22 coupling, so technically the connection would be OK - but would it not mean too much resistance for water flow? Sadly, each circuit has 3-4 large radiators...

Comment: I have concerns about converting a system designed with 22mm pipes to use controls designed for smaller pipes.  I don't know enough to express these concerns intelligently. and I may be wrong.  However I don't see why the reducing coupling itself would be the issue.  Isn't that just a symptom?

Comment: @jay613 I understand your concerns - the 18mm limitation seems to come from the fact that these more modern systems are designed with way more circuits than our old house has... In a modern system, every radiator would have its own circuit - we only have 2 circuits feeding 8 radiators in total, plus a circuit for the lower level's floor heating arrangement...

So you're right - it is actually a symptom of the heating arrangement being way out of date... Will need changes to be done in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing (for now) that the threaded copper fitting shown in the question is intended to be used with a flat rubber washer, I think it would work unreliably with the conical threaded connections on the manifold shown in the question.  The washer would not seat well, it would tend to be pushed into the fitting and distorted.

If you want to use your existing 22mm copper pipes with new controls that are only meant to be used with copper pipes up to 18mm you should find a way to properly adapt them.     Ask a good local plumbing supply store if they can find suitable couplings, or a combination of things that will do the job properly.   It's unlikely you're the first person to want to do this.

Comment: Actually, the plumbing shop advised to find a manifold that either use the flat washer type connection, or is suitable for thread-sealing kind of connection. They *are* available, but it seems these days harder to find.